# Why Can't I add a foreign key in Laravel Migration?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am going to first acknowledge that this question has been asked several times on SO. I have looked at the answers on those other question and tried them, and none seem to work. For example, I have ensured that both fields have the same data type, both tables are InnoDB, and that the tables are being created in the right time sequence, meaning that the table I am referencing,"Answers", was created before the respondents table.
So, what I am trying to do is add a key. Each respondent could have many answers. Note that I am using the resp_id as my primary key on the respondents table. I have also tried creating another field for the resp_id that was not the primary key, but that didn't work either.
Here is my migration for both tables.

Respondents Table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('respondents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('resp_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('survey_id');
        $table->string('resp_access_code', 20);
        $table->string('resp_email', 80)->nullable();
        $table->string('resp_first', 80);
        $table->string('resp_last', 80);
        $table->tinyInteger('resp_alt')->default(0);
        $table->string('cust_1', 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('cust_2', 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('cust_3', 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('cust_4', 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('cust_5', 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('cust_6', 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('cust_7', 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('cust_8', 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('cust_9', 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('cust_10', 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('cust_11', 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('cust_12', 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('cust_13', 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('cust_14', 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('cust_15', 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('cust_16', 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('cust_17', 255)->nullable();
        $table->integer('rentable_square_feet')->nullable();
        $table->float('resp_compensation', 10, 2)->default(0.00);
        $table->float('resp_bonus', 10, 2)->nullable()->default(0.00);
        $table->float('resp_benefit_pct', 5, 4)->default(0.0000);
        $table->float('resp_total_compensation', 10, 2)->default(0.00);
        $table->datetime('start_dt')->nullable();
        $table->datetime('last_dt')->nullable();
        $table->integer('last_page_id')->nullable();
        $table->tinyInteger('survey_completed')->default(0);
        $table->tinyInteger('invitation_sent')->unsigned()->default(0)->comment('0 - not sent.  1-> how many sent');
        $table->integer('survey_reviewed')->default(0);
        $table->datetime('last_invitation_sent')->nullable();
        $table->string('reportLocation1', 200)->nullable();
        $table->string('reportLocation2', 200)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('survey_id')->references('survey_id')->on('survey');
        $table->foreign('resp_id')->references('resp_id')->on('answers');
    });
}
```

And the answers table:

```
   public function up()
{
    Schema::create('answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('resp_id');
        $table->integer('question_id');
        $table->integer('answer_value');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Does anyone see anything wrong with the way I am approaching this? If so, please give me some guidance on how to solve it.

Comment: you are creating a foreign key on top of a primary key. you should create a foreign key on answers table. move $table->foreign... to answers table and update reference/ timestamps accordingly.

Comment: `$table->foreign('survey_id')->references('survey_id')->on('survey')` Are you sure it's not `surveys` (plural)? And `$table->foreign('resp_id')->references('resp_id')->on('answers')` should rather be in the answers table migration

Comment: @PrinceDorcis, that one works. It is the $table->foreign('resp_id')->references('resp_id')->on('answers'); that throws the error when doing the migration.

Comment: @AnuratChapanond, You are correct. Please make your comment an answer and I will accept it. I am still shaking my head in disbelief that I didn't catch that.

Comment: @Premisoft glad it works out for you, no need to give me any more pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing to the wrong key:

```
$table->foreign('survey_id')->references('id')->on('survey');
$table->foreign('resp_id')->references('id')->on('answers');
```

Im not sure if

```
$table->id();
```

is shorthand for

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```

but thats the way I define primary keys on my tables.

*edit*
It's laravel 8 I see + you can only reference on non primary keys if they are unique, so make them unique with ->unique() on table definition.

Comment: Hi Steven, No, that isn't what I want. ID on answers will only give me the answer id of any answer that has the id matching the resp_id on respondents. I need to get all answers that match a particular respondent. That is why I added the resp_id field to the answer table.
Also, $table->id is shorthand. It is new to Laravel 8.

Comment: Good point and one that actually didn't come to mind. I can't do that in this situation because a respondent can have many answers and so the resp_id would not be unique. The comment above by @Anurat Chapanond was the answer I needed. I had my tables reversed for this relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Define the foreign key in your "respondents" table like this:

```
$table->bigInteger('survey_id')->unsigned->nullable();
$table->foreign('survey_id')->references('id')->on('survey');
$table->bigInteger('resp_id')->unsigned->nullable()
$table->foreign('resp_id')->references('resp_id')->on('answers');
```

Make sure that your survey table name is plural or singular.